# ORA-02289: sequence does not exist, error in hibernbate

Tags: java, database, hibernate

ORA-02289: sequence does not exist, error in hibernbate

Comment: For Oracle you need a sequence in your DB and in your Entity something like this: `@Id
 @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "yourSeq", name = "yourSeq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "yourSeq")`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Oracle you can't autogenerate values, you should create a sequence (let's call it VEHICLE_SEQ). Then you should put this annotations on your id:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ", sequenceName = "VEHICLE_SEQ")
```

To create the sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE VEHICLE_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Comment: You have created the sequence (db side)?

Comment: You shoud also create a sequence in your oracle db (calling it VEHICLE_SEQ)

Comment: i dont have privilege to create sequence,is there any other way we can work this out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108183/discussion-between-harish-amarnath-and-baldurian).

Comment: Not if your database is Oracle. But, if someone told you to create an entity for an oracle db they should know you need to create sequences.

Answer (score 1):

You can use as below, if you are not really focussing only on sequence number to generate the ID

```
@Column(name = "XYZ", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid.hex")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid.hex", strategy = "uuid.hex")
@Id
```

This generates the new number whenever a new records gets inserted

Comment: public class Vehicle {
 @Id @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid.hex")
 @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid.hex", strategy = "uuid.hex")  ************                                                                                            please take a look at this....Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of org.javab.Vehicle.vehicleid