# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-00917: missing comma

Tags: java, database, hibernate

```
package org.javab.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.Session; 
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.javab.Vehicle;
import org.javab.Twowheel;
import org.javab.Fourwheel;

public class Transport {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Twowheel Twowheel = new Twowheel();
        Twowheel.setTwowheel("two");
        Twowheel.setVehicleid(1);
        Twowheel.setVehiclename("bike and cycle");



        Fourwheel Fourwheel = new Fourwheel();  
        Fourwheel.setVehicleid(2);
        Fourwheel.setFourwheel("four");
        Fourwheel.setVehiclename("car and bus");

        Vehicle Vehicle = new Vehicle();
        Vehicle.setVehiclename("vehicle name");
        Vehicle.setVehicleid(3);



         @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        SessionFactory sessionfactory =new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session =sessionfactory.openSession();

      session.beginTransaction();   

      session.save(Vehicle);
      session.save(Fourwheel);
      session.save(Twowheel);
      session.getTransaction().commit();

      session.close();
    }

}
```

The model class i have are below..

```
package org.javab;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
        name="vehicle d type",
        discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Vehicle {
    @Id /*@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO,generator = "SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ", sequenceName = "VEHICLE_SEQ", initialValue = 1)*/
    public int getVehicleid() {
        return vehicleid;
    }
    public void setVehicleid(int vehicleid) {
        this.vehicleid = vehicleid;
    }
    public String getVehiclename() {
        return vehiclename;
    }
    public void setVehiclename(String vehiclename) {
        this.vehiclename = vehiclename;
    }
    private int vehicleid;
        private String vehiclename;
}
```

> Class TwoWheel

```
package org.javab;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class Twowheel extends Vehicle {
private String Twowheel;

public String getTwowheel() {
    return Twowheel;
}

public void setTwowheel(String twowheel) {
    Twowheel = twowheel;
}

}
```

> Class FourWheel

```
package org.javab;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class Fourwheel extends Vehicle{
private String fourwheel;

public String getFourwheel() {
    return fourwheel;
}

public void setFourwheel(String fourwheel) {
    this.fourwheel = fourwheel;
}
}
```

the `Exception` which i have been getting is ...

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Hibernate: insert into Vehicle (vehiclename, vehicle d type, vehicleid) values (?, 'Vehicle', ?)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-00917: missing comma

    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2849)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3290)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1081)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at org.javab.hibernate.Transport.main(Transport.java:42)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00917: missing comma

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1010)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1315)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
    ... 16 more
```

> hibernate.cfg.xml.

```
  <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>

    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@sae.corpxxxxxxxxxxxe.com:1600/crmrtld</property>
    <property name="connection.username">XXXXXXXXX</property>
    <property name="connection.password">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXr</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <!-- <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property> -->

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <!-- Name the annotated Entity -->
    <mapping class="org.javab.Userdetails"></mapping>
      <mapping class="org.javab.Vehicle"></mapping>
        <mapping class="org.javab.Fourwheel"></mapping>
          <mapping class="org.javab.Twowheel"></mapping>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

it was working fine with the 10g dialect and everything,,
please also help me with generating id..i cant generate id in oracle?
now i just hardcoded them just to make it work..

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["ERROR: ORA-00917: missing comma" when using Hibernate with an existing sequence in oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431863/error-ora-00917-missing-comma-when-using-hibernate-with-an-existing-sequence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DiscriminatorColumn` is supposed to be name of the column. And in your case the name is `"vehicle d type"`. And it's not allowed to use space in name of column.

So use some reasonable name for `DiscriminatorColumn`. Note that this column must exist in SQL table.

Also note that for the inherited classes you need to specify `@DiscriminatorValue("class-specific-value")` so hibernate can distinguish which class it actually is.

Comment: thanks a lot!    but why i need to add @discriminator for my inherited class?

Comment: is there anyway i could add sequence to this project? oracle supports auto sequence?

Comment: @HarishAmarnath : Java supports sequences, take a look at [@GeneratedValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html#strategy--). `@DiscriminatorValue` identifies the type of the child class, `@DiscriminatorColumn` doesn't make sense without that - check this [tutorial](http://www.javatpoint.com/hibernate-table-per-hierarchy-using-annotation-tutorial-example)

Comment: Vyskovsky - please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36402384/ora-02289-sequence-does-not-exist-error-in-hibernbate.

Comment: i used @Generatedvalu, but i couldnt generate sequences..here in java.